# How to check a dict key?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I`m doing an unit test for the first time and I need to check if a success key is the same as the other one, how can I check a success key without checking the whole dictionary?
I just need to check the success key not all the other ones
I need to do it with assert using the unit test module

```
dict 1 = {'success': RC.input_validation, 
          'return_msg': return_msg, 
          'debug_data': debug_data}

dict 2 = {'success':  RC.success, 
          'return_msg': return_msg, 
          'debug_data': debug_data}

class MyTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_something(self):
        call_result = {}
        debug_data = []

        test = SetShape()
        call_result = SetShape.setShape(test, shapechoosing=1)
        debug_data.append(call_result)
        print("10")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Comment: Access the two keys' values and compare them with the assertion methods?

Comment: but like, I didn`t want to compare the two dictionaries, I wanted to compares just those 2 keys

Comment: So, do that then.

Comment: It's really not clear what the problem is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work for you.

```
dict_1 = {'success': "RC.input_validation", 
          'return_msg': "return_msg", 
          'debug_data': "debug_data"}

dict_2 = {'success':  "RC.success", 
          'return_msg': "return_msg", 
          'debug_data': "debug_data"}

dict_1.get('success')==dict_2.get('success')
```

Comment: This might work, but it's not ideal, cause it won't raise an error if the dicts are missing the `'success'` key.

Comment: Thats not part of your question though. Please be more careful when defining your question.

Comment: I'm not OP, just mentioning since OP seems like a newbie

Answer (score 1):

Access the values of the `'success'` key in each dictionary and check if they're equal

```
if dict1['success'] == dict2['success']:
    print("they're the same")
```

Comment: I get this error  if entry['success'] == RC.input_validation:
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

Comment: I know I changed your code but just he says it cant be an str

Comment: @LucasFernandes then it's a list, *not* a dictionary.

Comment: Do you guys have any idea of how to it with assert?

Comment: `assert dict1['success'] == dict2['success']`

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
if dict_1.get('success') == dict_2.get('success'):
   # your body of code
```

Hope it helps!!

Comment: This might work, but it's not ideal, cause it won't raise an error if the dicts are missing the `'success'` key.

Comment: Oh, in that case, wrapping this if condition around another if condition should do the trick where the outer if should be like `if 'success' in dict_1 and 'success' in dict_2:`

Comment: Again that might work, but it might be simpler to not have to handle that possibility and just error to stop execution. That's why I would recommend simply indexing: `dict_1['success'] == dict_2['success']`.

Comment: Do you have any ideas of how to it with assert?